# make background of sprite transparent in SDL

Tags: c++, c, sdl

How to change background color of sprites to transparent by changing alpha after loading it to a SDL_Surface. Are there any functions in SDL which use a floodfill kind of algorithm and change all pixel with a given color to transparent on the outside. I don't want it to happen inside the border of the sprite if the same color is used.

Sample Image:

[image: Sprite Image]

I would like to make the background blue here transparent before I blit it on the window surface using SDL_BlitSurface.

Comment: I think you do this with `SDL_SetColorKey()` - https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetColorKey but I don't know exactly how to do it, and the doco is inconclusive.

Comment: SDL_SetColorKey() works if the background color was not included in my palette for any sprite. I think most of my sprites don't have it and for the ones that do have, I will change the color by a small value and use it.

Comment: You can't just edit the base image to have an alpha-channel and transparent background?

Comment: Can't you change or copy-and-replace the image "offline" (ie: during development, rather than in the game)?

Answer (score 3):

Only a color key (`SDL_SetColorKey()`) or a full alpha channel are going to help you here.

Note, that you can provide an alpha channel in your source graphics if you use a format such as PNG. If you only sometimes need/want an alpha, then provide the alpha channel in your source graphics and use `SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode()` with `SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE` to blend without the alpha and `SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND` to blend with it.

Both `SDL_Surface` and `SDL_Texture` support `SDL_BlendMode`.

Even if SDL provided another method, such as the fill you mentioned. You wouldn't want to use that. It is more difficult, expensive, and unnecessary overhead. You should stick with best practices here.

You may want to look into `SDL_Texture` and `SDL_Renderer` and switch to using a "texture atlas" instead of individual surfaces/textures for each image to maximize performance.